# Access-VBA Non-Error Values Displaying as #Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to handle errors caused by blank fields in an Access database. I have a function that takes the `Latitude` field's value, parses it to another format (from DMS to decimal), and is used in a query as a new field. As long as `Latitude` contains a valid DMS value, this works as expected. However, if it does not, the new field (`decLat`) will contain `#Error`.

From my readings, this is typically caused by the value passed in being an Error itself. However, testing with IsError(doubLat) in the function itself shows that none of the outputs are Error.

My next attempt was to check whether the output was 0 (because the conversion function is meant to return that in event of an error), but that doesn't seem to be the issue either. So the question is, what causes the code below to return `#Error` when the input is null?

```
Function LatToDecimal(latIn As Variant) As String 'latIn is Variant as attempt at error handling. Will always be String or Null.
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If (latIn = "") Then
        GoTo ErrHandler
    ElseIf (IsNull(latIn)) Then GoTo ErrHandler
    End If
Restart:
    Dim SplitA() As String
    SplitA() = Split(latIn, "°") 'A(0) is DEG.
    Dim SplitB() As String
    If (UBound(SplitA) > 0) Then
        SplitB() = Split(SplitA(1), "'") 'B(0) is MIN.
    Else:
        LatToDecimal = "0"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim SplitC() As String
    If (UBound(SplitB) > 0) Then
        SplitC() = Split(SplitB(1), """") 'C(0) is SEC. C(1) is N/S.
    Else:
        LatToDecimal = "0"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim deg As Double
    Dim min As Double
    Dim sec As Double

    deg = CDbl(SplitA(0)) 'Assign more readable names.
    min = CDbl(SplitB(0))
    sec = CDbl(SplitC(0))

    Dim minM As Double 'Transitional value.
    Dim decDeg As Double 'decimal degrees

    'Conversion to decimal
    minM = min + (sec / 60)
    decDeg = deg + (minM / 60)
    If (SplitC(1) = "S") Then decDec = decDeg * -1

    'Return value
    LatToDecimal = decDeg
    GoTo Finished

ErrHandler:
    latIn = "0°0'0"""
    MsgBox ("Error!")
    GoTo Restart
Finished:
End Function

'Wrapper to convert decimal latitude (from LatToDecimal) into Double values. Still need one for longitude.
Function doubLat(ByVal latIn As String) As Double
    Dim newLat As Double
    newLat = CDbl(LatToDecimal(latIn))
    doubLat = newLat
    If (doubLat = 0) Then doubLat = 0#
End Function
```

The function `doubLat` is the one called by my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what causes the code below to return #Error when the input is null?

Your query uses your *doubLat()* function:

```
Function doubLat(ByVal latIn As String) As Double
```

If you called that function with Null in an Immediate window session, Access would throw error #94, *"Invalid use of Null"*.  The error handling you included within the function does not come into play because the function does not even run.  (By the way, checking `IsNull(latIn)` is pointless because you declared *latIn* `As String` ... and that means *latIn* can never be Null.)

When you use that function as a query field expression and give it Null, Access just displays *#Error* in the query result set.

Avoid that problem by substituting something else (an empty string?) for Null when you call the function ...

```sql
SELECT doubLat(IIf(YourField Is Null, '', YourField))
```

Or you could use the VBA `Nz()` function ...

```sql
SELECT doubLat(Nz(YourField, ''))
```

Comment: I really should have caught that, given that my comments indicate I had a similar issue when implementing LatToDecimal... thanks for speaking to the blind man.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the query's *#Error* response is not real useful.  You can get better information by exploring the query issue in the Immediate window ... `? doubLat(Null)` would give you a clear picture of the real problem.

Comment: The Immediate window comes up blank, I'm afraid! Even when the error occurred, the query still completed without hanging in the middle of a function. (As you said, it wasn't run at all.)

Comment: Not sure we're on the same page, Nathaniel.  I meant paste `? doubLat(Null)` into a new line in the Immediate window and press `Enter`.  Access should respond with error #94, *"Invalid use of Null"*.  Isn't that what you see?

Comment: I have thoroughly misunderstood what the Immediate window is meant to do; I'm used to working in Java, so I assumed it was a debug tool that shows the status of all open variables while the code is suspended. I believe I understand now, though.